# Use msal-react with multiple instances/providers (Azure AD and Azure B2C)

Tags: reactjs, msal-react

I have a react app using Azure B2C for user registration/login (with msal-react). Now I also need to add login for internal users with Azure AD, but I don't see any way to add multiple msal instaces in the same app. I have the normal setup:

```
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
<MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
Rest of app
</MsalProvider>
```

But I don't see how I can add another provider for AzureAD. Federating AzureAD into B2C is not an option as there needs to be a bigger separation between external and interal login.

Do anyone know if this can be achived with msal-react or du I have to use msal.js directly?

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same situation and I believe I have made it a little further than you've described by using two separate instances and two separate providers (each one wrapping the protected components):

Using React Router 6 to create routes:

```
{
    path: '/portal',
    element: 
        <MsalProvider instance={B2CMsalInstance}>
            <B2CAuthenticatedRoutes component={<Outlet />} />
        </MsalProvider>,
    children: ...
},
{
    path: '/portalAdmin',
    element:
        <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
            <MSALAuthenticatedRoutes component={<Outlet />} />
        </MsalProvider>,
    children: ...
}
```

HOWEVER, it seems that the msal-react library mixes the context from both these instances, probably because it's storing data in the session cache. I haven't figured out how to keep the logins separate. Have you been able find a good solution for your initial issue?